# R timeBasedSeq must quote to avoid errors in dates before 1000 CE. But how to deal with BCE dates?

Tags: r, date, sequence

I'm working on paleoclimate data and need time series for long time periods. To help create an xts object, I used the convenient timeBasedSeq function. According to the docs you don't need to quote the date range, as it will be handled internally. It turns out that this is true for dates from 1000 CE onward. However, there is very inconsistent behavior for dates earlier than 1000 CE. For example, the following commands give correct monthly date sequences for the years 1550-1560 CE:

```
timeBasedSeq(155001/1560)  
timeBasedSeq(1550/156012)  
timeBasedSeq(155001/156012)
```

For dates before the year 1000 CE, the results are inconsistent. The command...

```
timeBasedSeq(550/56012)
```

Produces a correct monthly sequence for the decade between 550-560 CE. And the command...

```
timeBasedSeq(0550/0560)
```

Produces a correct annual sequence for the same decade between 550-560 CE. But the commands...

```
timeBasedSeq(55001/560)  
timeBasedSeq(055001/0560)
```

Generate an error:

```
Error in seq.int(r1$mon, 12 * (to0$year - r1$year) + to0$mon, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

Worse, the commands...

```
timeBasedSeq(55001/56012)
timeBasedSeq(055001/056012)
```

...do not raise an error, but produce the wrong date sequence: an annual sequence for the century from 5500 to 5601 CE (far in the future).

Quoting these latter problematic commands yields correct results. For example,...

```
timeBasedSeq("55001/560")
```

Gives a correct monthly sequence between the years 550-560 while the same command with no quotes raises an error. So, regardless of the docs, it seems like it would be a good idea to always quote the date range specification in timeBasedSeq.

However, I can't find any way to generate a sequence of dates prior to 0 CE -- that is dates BC or BCE. Negative signs seem to be ignored by timeBasedSeq, even when the date range is quoted. Does anyone have a suggestion for generating a sequence that runs monthly from 2000 BCE to 500 CE?

Comment: `ym <- as.yearmon(seq(550, 560 + 11/12, 1/12))` will give a `"yearmon"` class monthly sequence and `as.Date(ym)` will give the same sequence  as `"Date"` class.

Comment: OK. And seq.Date also creates a date sequence. But AFAICT, as.yearmon (like the other date sequence commands) will not create BC/BCE dates. After writing this note and question, I finally found a comment from Joshua Ulrich several years ago that indicates the inability to deal with any time series older than 2015 years ago is inherent in R. If this is indeed true, it would be nice (a wish) if someone could manage to extend time series farther back for those of us in the historical sciences who regularly deal with time...and time that extends back beyond the last couple millennia.

Comment: That would be a bug in yearmon.   Perhaps to get around all this you could just use zoo with an index of the form year + month/12 where Jan=0, ..., Dec=11/12 as your index (which are the internal values used by yearmon).

Comment: I don't understand how that would produce dates prior to AD 1 (i.e., BC or BCE dates)

Comment: The point is that you would just be using plain numbers so there would be no problem caused by any of these date or datetime classes.